Why is the logarithm of the likeilhood function significant?
In maximum likelihood we often use the logarithm of the likelihood function rather than the likelihood function directly. One reason for this is that it is convenient for numerical optimization methods that are used to maximize the likelihood function. However, it seems to be useful theoretically beyond mere "convenience".

The maximum likelihood estimator is asymptotically normally distributed with a covariance matrix given by the inverse of the Fisher information matrix $\mathcal{I}^{-1}$. However $\mathcal{I}$ is defined in terms of the log-likelihood rather than the likelihood
Likewise, the Cramer-Rao bound again involves the Fisher information defined in terms of the log-likelihood rather than the likelihood.

So there seems to be something of theoretical interest about looking at the logarithm of the likelihood rather than the likelihood. Can anyone provide insight or intuition about why this is the case?

For independent samples, log likelihoods add.  For iid samples, the CLT applies.  Go on from there.
